# tabulator .tabulator-row-even overridden but .tabulator-row-odd is not

Tags: css, sass, tabulator

i'm trying to set ".tabulator-row-even" and ".tabulator-row-odd" colors on a tabulator table.

".tabulator-row-even" is being overridden by tabulator.scss

".tabulator-row-odd" is not overridden, I can change this color.

my style.css has these lines:

```
.tabulator-row-odd {
    background-color: #553333;
}
.tabulator-row-even {
    background-color: #335533;
}
```

computed properties on Safari:

```
#553333.tabulator-row-odd   style.css:23
#fff.tabulator-row  tabulator.scss:1001
#fff.tabulator .…lator-table    tabulator.scss:1001

#efefef.tabulator-r…or-row-even tabulator.scss:1001
#335533.tabulator-row-even  style.css:26
#fff.tabulator-row  tabulator.scss:1001
```

Comment: Please add a Jsfiddle demo

Comment: I worked around it by adding another class to the elements. I'm using nodejs on a raspberry pi. I don't know how to use fiddle other than for simple things. Is there a way to disable sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try ?

```
.tabulator-row-odd {
    background-color: #553333 !important;
}
.tabulator-row-even {
    background-color: #335533 !important;
}
```

Comment: The reason this worked is because the the classes are specified with the .tabulator-row class. so you need to specify the selector as .tabulator-row.tabulator-row-odd in order to override them